# 'package:flushbar/flushbar_route.dart': Failed assertion: line 308 pos 18: 'overlayEntries.isEmpty': is not true

Tags: flutter

I am using this library ..but I got this error

```
  Flushbar(
    title: 'Warning',
    message: "You have no Internet",
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.error_outline,
      size: 28,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    leftBarIndicatorColor: Colors.blue.shade300,
    duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
  )..show(context);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After using  this library with same code  resolve my issue

https://pub.dev/packages/another_flushbar

import 'package:another_flushbar/flushbar.dart';